# Embedd RSS Feed into HTML Document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, rss

Is there an easy way to embed an RSS feed into a html document with no styling using the site's native stylesheet? (Not using an RSS Feed reader)

Answer (score 0):

You can style a RSS(XML) file with CSS but if you would embed it you need to use a server-side language such as PHP to read the RSS file and parse it.

It could be done with a iframe too but I can't recommend that solution.